# About the meaning(s) of "to have much to recommend something"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Not sure if the mentioned expression in the title is just, I tried to figure it out based on my language skills/instincts. It is a citation found in a programming book. Sometimes between the title and the section I can find citations; this is one of them.

> Omniscience has much to recommend it. Failing that, attention to details would be useful.

I am not sure how to understand it, never heard the expression before. My hunch is that the author of the citation tries to recommend to pay attention to details, since one is not omniscient (?).

I'd be thankful to learn about this more. How is the expression/citation meant ?

Comment: Hello, Ely. This expression can be looked up in an online dictionary (eg M-W, Longman), and it is strongly recommended that that is always done before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression used to suggest that something or someone have good qualities about themselves.

> [have much to recommend it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20much%20to%20recommend%20it)
> (idiom)- *or have much to recommend him/her*
>
> - to have many good or attractive qualities
>
> *As a vacation destination, the area has much to recommend it.* —
> *All the nominees for the award had much to recommend them.*

(Merriam-Webster)

( Omniscience is a very good thing, but if you are not omniscient, attention to details  would be useful.)

Comment: In the current example, the circuitous wording adds to the irony. Of course, we're not omniscient, and whether it's recommended or not, we cannot attain it. Thus it's not just useful to attend to details. It's what programmers must do, and the rest of us, too.